# How do I get rid of BSON objects after a mapReduce?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mapreduce

I'm a complete beginner to map-reduce and relatively new with MongoDB. I am trying to perform a map-reduce on a collection (by the name Customers).

My map function:

```
var map = function() {
    emit(this.nationality, {edad: this.age, telefono: this.phone_number});
};
```

My reduce function:

```
var reduce = function(key, values) {
    return Array.sum(values);
};
```

I call mapReduce() as follows:

```
db.Customers.mapReduce( map , reduce , { out : { inline : 1}} );
```

Finally my result field is:

```
    "results" : [
            {
                    "_id" : "Brazil",
                    "value" : {
                            "edad" : 34,
                            "telefono" : null
                    }
            },
            {
                    "_id" : "Colombia",
                    "value" : "[object BSON][object BSON]"
            },
            {
                    "_id" : "Germany",
                    "value" : {
                            "edad" : 18,
                            "telefono" : 2986
                    }
            }, ...
```

As you can see it contains BSON objects, the problem being that I can't find a way to visualize the content of these BSONs, not even in Robomongo.

I have looked for other answers in Stackoverflow addressing this, so far I have found this:
"Your reduce function must return the same format that your map function emits". But being honest, I haven´t managed to figure out how do I apply it to solve my problem. I mean, what is the format of my emit? And in which format is the output of my reduce function?

If anyone could provide me the exact code lines, my gratitude in advance.

Comment: It happened to me as well. I tried to work on a huge stock database with `mapReduce` and it threw the error to me. But if I limited the function to 100, it worked fine. it seems there were some errors not thrown within the function.